# Creating an animation using ImageMagick

Tags: matlab, animation, imagemagick

I have produced a series of images using matlab and am trying to create an animation. I have been using ImageMagick and have been using the command window to create my animation.

I first type into the command window:

```
cd C:/Users/Julian/Desktop/Research Program/13700 Images
```

I then type:

```
convert -delay 0 -loop 0 images_*.jpg animated.gif
```

But the error "Invalid Parameter - 0" is shown. The same error is displayed for any positive integer.

Why is this not working?

Note: each of my 13,700 images is roughly 340 KB.

**Update:**

The following command removes the previous error message:

```
magick convert -delay 0 -loop 0 images_*.jpg animated.gif
```

But still no animation is produced.

Comment: When you use convert or magick convert on Windows it tries to use ImageMagick 6, not ImageMagick 7. That requires that you install the "legacy" components when you installed ImageMagick. If you want to use ImageMagick 7, then use only magick. Try `magick -delay 0 images_*.jpg -loop 0 animated.gif` The -loop command should come after reading the images.

Comment: @fmw42 It doesn't appear to work. I'm unsure if it's taking some time to load or if it is not recognising the command.

Comment: @fmw42 I just trialled your command with five images and it worked. Perhaps it may take several hours to convert the 13,700 images.

Comment: If your images are very large, they all would need to be stored in RAM as well as the output. Do you have enough RAM? If not, it may crash unless you have set up enough space mapped to disk. If you have done that, then it will take longer. What are the width and height of your images and how much RAM do you have?

Comment: @fmw42 Exactly that happend, it crashed. The dimensions of my images are 1800×1470 and I have 8.00 GB of RAM. I have moved all my images to a 32 GB USB. I used similar commands as above, but the following error is given - "unable to open image 'images_*.jpg': Invalid argument @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3496." Confused as what to do next.

Comment: 1 of your images needs 64 Mb (as 24-bits) in RAM. You have 13,700 images. That means you need 876 GB for all your input images, not counting the output animation. I do not think this is practical. Even if you use disk in place of RAM, it will take a very long time to process.

Comment: @fmw42 How did you know 1 image needs 64 Mb?

Comment: `@JulianAngussmith` If your file is color then ImageMagick will read it and convert to 24-bits (3 bytes) color. So 1800*1470*3 = 8 MB. (Sorry I made a mistake above). So 8*1300=10.4 GB. That is for the input. The output would need to be in RAM also before writing it. If the output are gifs, then perhaps 1800*1470*1Byte = 2.6 GB. So you would need about 14 GB, if I have not made any more mistakes. But other programs need RAM as well.

Comment: @fmw42 Do you know of any online tools that can do this? I don't think it's practical to do it any other way.

Comment: No. I have not created many big animations. You could try making a video using ffmpeg. If you go ahead with ImageMagick, then you will likely need to modify your policy.xml file to permit use of all your RAM and use some memory mapped to disk to supplement.

Comment: `-delay 0` is valid ? I'm not sure.